# How to measure the intensity of a pen-type laser beam?

Tags: optics, diffraction

I need to measure the intensity of a green pen-type laser, rated at $500\,\mathrm{mW}$, before and after it undergoes Bragg diffraction by a synthetic Opal cube. I've basically zero experience with such measurements.

The first port of call appeared to me [an instrument like this one](https://www.labfacility.com/digital-light-meter-gm1010.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAoNWOBhCwARIsAAiHnEgEL_vs0HRfR_2aeSl9XpM1F2voWiNfswU7jf-tQaWB9xhVOePLKpAaAk14EALw_wcB) but I've no idea of its suitability for my purpose.

Specifically:

1. I'm unsure whether $500\,\mathrm{mW}$ would fall in the advertised $0 - 200,000\,\mathrm{lux}$ range,
2. whether such an instrument would be able to cope with the 'point-like' shape of the beam, without causing sensor-overload (as happens with digital cameras when I try to photograph laser beams),
3. how does the distance between the laser source and the sensor affect the reading (output)?

For context, the experimental work I'm referring to [can be found here](https://dispatches-from-the-us-of-mordor.blogspot.com/2021/12/bragg-diffraction-by-synthetic-opal-of.html).

Perhaps there are other types of instrument out there that are more suited for my purpose?

---

If I use an ND:

[image: CPL]

because of the inevitable reflection $I_R$, how do I determine:

$$\frac{I_T}{I_0}$$

Comment: (+1) If your laser is really around 500 mW, which is rather high (and dangerous) for a laser pointer, you can attenuate the beam with crossed polarizers (calcite, not plastic sheet) and likely use the power meter you linked. You might also need a little beam expansion (say 5x) to avoid damaging the optical sensor. I suggest not directly using neutral density filters to attenuate the unexpanded beam prior to measurement because they can get “burned” by intense, small diameter lasers. At least beam expand and then use the ND filters.

Comment: You link is not suitable at all - it looks like a light sensor for photographers, giving an estimate of ambient light - the laser would blow it away. You need either (a) a real laser power meter (pricey), (b) follow @EdV advice, or (c) use ND filters and a semiconductor diode. I would use ND filters, since you may need to vary the dynamic range to measure the original and Bragg reflections accurately.

Comment: @ both: I do have 2 more lasers, one red ($650\,\mathrm{nm}$), one purple, both rated at $< 1\,\mathrm{mW}$. So these would be more suitable for an off-the-shelf light meter. I thought also to use a 'diffuser' to spread out the laser beam a little. I have an ND but it doesn't seem to filter out that much light. What say you?

Comment: @EdV How does one achieve 'beam expansion'?

Comment: @EdV Okay, thanks. Just ping it here.

Comment: Can you give a sense of your budget and how accurate this needs to be?

Comment: @EdV Thanks you Ed. Will scrutinise later today.

Comment: You can make a beam expander by simply using a simple cheap Galilean telescope in reverse and the photodiode’s photo current can be measured directly, using the DMM in ammeter mode. You can get inexpensive photodiodes on ebay and probably ND filters as well. Calcite polarizers are pricey, but ND filters are fine, if you do not burn them: do not hit the ND filter in the center with the unattenuated beam!

Comment: @Gilbert Hi Gilbert. I'm a degree chemist but right now I'm not an 'institutionalised scientist' (I run a bar in Scarborough, FCS) And with Covid ravaging my industry money is very tight. Re. accuracy, my purpose is to characterise this synth. Opal in terms of micro-globular structure. A high degree of accuracy of $I_D/I_0$ values may not be required for this purpose.

Comment: @EdV Re your last remark: not even with a $<1\,\mathrm{mW}$ beam? I've added a question to that effect.

Comment: For the sub-mW  laser pointers you can skip the filters and beam expander: they are too puny to damage anything. I am a retired chemistry professor who did research in analytical laser spectroscopy and I have used lasers with significant power, e.g., 22 W (all lines) argon ion CW laser. Your green laser pointer, if anywhere near 500 mW, is dangerous if you catch a reflection in the eye. Please be careful!

Comment: Just saw the addition to your post. A neutral density filter just attenuates the incident beam by the specified (acceptably wavelength-independent) factor of 10^-(neutral density). So ND = 1 means filter transmittance = transmitted intensity / incident intensity = 10^-1 = 0.1.

Comment: @EdV Withe the $532\,\mathrm{nm}$ green laser I can hit a church spire about $0.5\,\mathrm{mile}$ away. Care needs to be taken, indeed. But I'm familiar with lasers and their dangers.  Thanks for your help (all).

Comment: @EdV Oh I see: the 'attenuation factor' accounts for any reflection then, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132908/discussion-between-ed-v-and-gert).

Comment: @EdV one should be careful with the marking of ND filters, see e.g. my question [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102776/26253).

Comment: @Ruslan Indeed, but good quality inconel ND filters, from reputable companies, are worth the money and reasonably accurate. I would never assume high accuracy without testing against some other method, e.g., crossed high quality calcite polarizers. But your point is taken: if the OP wants accurate ratios, then the ND filter’s actual transmittance at 532 nm needs to be accurately known if it is only used in only one of the two measurements that are used in the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the shape of the beam (e.g. Gaussian) it's enough to get a power meter and measure the total power. However, we usually used a so called [*beam profiler*](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3483). We build it ourself using a ccd chip and matlab, but "every" optical lab has one, nowadays. So, if you don't have one, why not ask a colleague.

An alternative (simpler) method is to use a translation stage, a razor plate and a power meter: recording the power for different cuts of the beam and assuming that the beam is rotational symmetric, you are able to determine the shape of the beam.

Comment: *So, if you don't have one, why not ask a colleague.* I work alone, in a 'backyard' laboratory.

Comment: If you know how to program you should probably by a CCD camera for about 50 USD and fir the resulting power profile. The only important thing is that you dismantle the ccd chip so that no focussing optics is in front of the chip.